# NHibernate: Combining result transformers?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I'm working with the criteria API, querying against a mapping file that I cannot really change. There is a root entity with many child entities joined to it and certain queries have required us to add

```
criteria.SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);
```

in order to avoid getting duplicate entities when there are multiple SQL result-lines due to the joins. The problem is that now I also want to apply an alias-to-bean transformer, like so:

```
criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(MyDto)));
```

Using either one of these works great. However, I need to combine them: I want to load only the required columns into a DTO object, and also get only distinct root entities. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load only required column into DTO you can use projection with DistinctEntityRootTransformer as follows

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(YourEntity));
criteria.SetProjection(
Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Property"), "Property")));

criteria.SetResultTransformer(
new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(MyDto)));

IList list = criteria.List();
```